# Display JIRA content in Confluence for anonymous users of Confluence

Tags: jira, confluence

I want to display JIRA details such as issue titles, a version roadmap, and the issues raised/resolved graph for projects in a Confluence site. This is fine for folks that are logged in but I need it to work for anonymous access as well. I don't want to have to set up anonymous access in JIRA for the project as it contains other details in the comments, etc.

I have followed everything that I can find as far as setting up Application Links between the two and can get the issues to display if I enter an account in the Basic Access tab of the application links.

Using the developer tools in the browser I can see an OAuth error when the gadget on the Confluence page tries to make a request.

Is there a way that Confluence can impersonate another user when it queries JIRA?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you want to do something impossible. As I understand it, there are the following options for using JIRA content inside Confluence:

- Use the authenticated user of Confluence in JIRA.
- Use an anonymous user for public issues in JIRA.
- Use a pre-determined user (not recommended): This will show in public the user name **and password** in Confluence.

So you have the following options:

- Use issue security in JIRA, and set the comments in your issues only be available for a special group.
- Ensure that the users you want to get access to are not contained in the special group.

See the documentation about ["Trusted Communication"](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+Up+Trusted+Communication+between+JIRA+and+Confluence), especially the following part:

> Display the JIRA issues which the logged-in user is authorised to see. And if the user is not logged in, display only issues which allow unrestricted viewing.

Comment: I'm looking into the issue security schemes and access permissions but cannot see a permission that restricts access for viewing comments, only adding, editing, etc. Is it something that gets set by default when you actually create the comment?

Comment: If your JIRA is [configured like that](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Configuring+JIRA+Options), you are able to restrict the visibility for issues to groups of person in your project. So this may help to hide some parts that should not be visible to all.